# How to solve these problems dealing with flowcharts?

Tags: flowchart

I am not able to comprehend the meaning in the general sense. I have tried all the online resources and books available to understand what this symbols mean and have quite naturally arrived at this. However when they are connected I am not able to understand how the values will be replaced by one another. A guidance about the same will be most certainly welcome.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is about general arithmetic and conditional statements, it doesn't matter how the values get replaced, but what is shown is an array or list of numbers that can be altered or accessed at specific locations

Read the instructions, do the math, then when it asks a question, follow the yes or no lines...

For the first question, can you ever reach the END? If not, you're in an infinite loop.

For the second question, same thing, but the end is a guaranteed state and it wants the answer in the box